# How do I control CompOption "multiline" in a regex-tdfa regular expression? (Haskell)

Tags: regex, haskell

Haskell noob here. I'm using regex-tdfa (for no particular reason) to (attempt to) match multiline chunks of code files (XAML, and, yes, I know about regexes and parsing XML and the the-ponies-they-come post).

If I use a simple regex in code like

```
fileContents =~ "<UserControl.Resources>"
```

I get hits in my files. Yay.

If I "upgrade" the regex to something like "<UserControl.Resources>.*</UserControl.Resources>", then I get no hits. So, I'm thinking my problem is multiline regexes and convincing the engine to match across multiple lines.

The thing is, I'm such a rank noob I have no idea how to do that. All I know is what I've learned from *Real World Haskell* and *Learn You a Haskell*, and those don't talk about regex compilation options.

So, I can force results like

```
fileContents =~ "<UserControl.Resources>" :: (String, String, String)
```

But that's all I know.

How do I turn multiline OFF? (I think it's ON, for some reason.)

Comment: Since you know it doesn't make sense to attempt to parse XML with regular expressions, why are you doing it? By the way, the prettiest Haskell API for parsing regular languages is `regex-applicative`.

Comment: I'm hacking, is why. Thanks for the pointer to regex-applicative. Bear in mind: Haskell noob. This is a Perl script written in Haskell. I'm sure applicative stuff is wonderful, but I'm not there yet.

Comment: Great things about applicative and monadic parsing libraries: they're easy to learn, and once you've learned one they all look familiar. One of the most popular and easiest to use is `attoparsec`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition of a compilation options for `regex-tdfa` may be found here:

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-tdfa-1.2.0/docs/src/Text-Regex-TDFA-Common.html#CompOption

The documentation says that `multiLine` is set to `True` by default.

Here is a way to compile and execute regular expressions with custom options:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

import Text.Regex.TDFA

toRegex = makeRegexOpts defaultCompOpt{multiline=False} defaultExecOpt

test str =
  if match (toRegex "<Tag>.*</Tag>") str
    then putStrLn "matches"
    else putStrLn "does not match"

test2 fileContents =
    match (toRegex "<Tag>.*</Tag>") fileContents :: (String, String, String)
```

Note that `match` is polymorphic just like `=~` is.

You can find code which uses custom regex options in the hledger-lib package:

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hledger-lib-0.26/docs/src/Hledger-Utils-Regex.html#Regexp

Comment: Beautiful, many thanks. It works like a champ (but you already knew that :) ).